# Top 10 Highest Records in Map Display

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

A silly question but is there any way out of the box to run a query to select the top 10 highest records based on a specific field for the current extent of a map display? I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with an enterprise geodatabase stored in any DBMS supported, you could use SQL TOP query. I'd just create a copy of the layer in the TOC and then setup the definition query for that layer (Layer Properties > Definition Query tab), but you could also use this syntax directly in the Select By Attributes dialog.

```
Meters in (select top 10 [Meters] from testgdb.dbo.streets order by [Meters] desc)
```

The same is applicable for personal geodatabases - you could use this syntax in Select By Attributes (this is because the personal gdb is stored as Microsoft Access which enables us using SQL).

```
[ELEVATION]  in (select top 10 [ELEVATION] from Fittings )
```

If you work with file geodatabases, you best choise imo is to use a Python code snippet:

```
fc = "Water distribution network fittings"
field = "ObjectId"

values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field)]
top_ten = sorted(values)[-10:] #adjust max rows count    
query = "\"{0}\" in {1}".format(field, tuple(top_ten))   
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "top10values", query)
```

Just modify the fc and the field variables, supplying the layer name and the field name. A new layer will be added to the TOC containing only reference to the top 10 rows.

If selecting max values with a variable top value (10,50,1000,etc.) will become your "hobby" for some time, I would recommend creating a Python script tool. Just add one input variable (TOP count) and then [place a GP tool icon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002400000005000000) somewhere close at any toolbar you have. By clicking the icon, you will get a GP tool dialog open where you supply a value. Then the tool is executed and you get your selection in the layer. [Python add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_add_in/014p00000025000000/) would also work for this.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the top 10 records works well but how would I get that 10 features to update when the user moves in their map display?

Comment: Absolutely. When you start the editing session for any of the layers that are copy of each other, they all reference to the same feature class. Any editing operations will be editing the feature class itself, so it does not matter which layer you work with.

Comment: Sorry Alex i think I worded the previous comment rather badly. So the top 10 select statement will return the top 10 records for the entire feature class of the entire spatial extent but what I'd like to do is return the top 10 records for the map display, so when the user pans or zooms the map it will give the top 10 records for the area being displayed. I hope that makes more sense

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that. You would need to set the arcpy.env.extent property. Please see my question here (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130048/output-extent-environment-is-not-respected-for-select-layer-by-attribute-arcgis). You could run Copy Features to create temp layer for each selection you do, but it would be nice to get Select Layer By Attribute working with the extent too.